# What is the name of the random variable $X$ with distribution $\mathbb P(X = i) = {n-i \choose k-1}/{n \choose k}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

Fix integers $1 \le k \le n$ and let ${n \choose k}$ be the binomial coefficient.

> **Question.**
> *What is the name of the random variable $X$ supported on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $\mathbb P(X = i) = {n-i \choose  k-1}/{n \choose k}$ ?*

Comment: Why not give it a name? This is based on the hockey-stick identity, so maybe hockey-stick distribution.

Comment: Alternately, uniformly pick an arbitrary subset of $[n]$ of size $k$. $X$ is the smallest element of such a set.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Indeed, thanks. I just thought this would correspond to some standard distribution with well-known properties, etc.

Comment: You are welcome! Not sure if there is an otherwise appealing name. Calculating $\mathbb E[X]$ is a problem that can actually be found in a few olympiad books, I believe that there are ways of doing it that are different from the definition. It is phrased as : what is the average value of the smallest element of a randomly chosen subset of $[n]$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a location-transformed special case of the [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution) $$\Pr[X = k] = \frac{\binom{k+r-1}{k}\binom{N-r-k}{K-k}}{\binom{N}{k}}, \quad k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, K\}.$$

To see this, let $k = i-1$, $r = 1$, $N = n$, and $K = n-k$:  we get

$$\Pr[X = i] = \frac{\binom{1}{1} \binom{n-1-(i-1)}{n-k-(i-1)}}{\binom{n}{n-k}} = \frac{\binom{n-i}{(n-i)-(k-1)}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\binom{n-i}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}, \quad i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n-k+1\},$$ where we have used the reflection identity $\binom{n}{n-k} = \binom{n}{k}$.  The location transformation applies in the sense that the support is shifted by $1$.  Note that your support is too large; for $i > n-k+1$, the numerator is zero.

I will leave it to the reader to browse the Wikipedia article to develop an interpretation of the meaning of such a distribution for this special case.

Comment: There is something weird. $K$ is supposed to be a constant, you make it depend on $k$, which is the value of the RV. And although $i$ is just $k$ shifted, you end up in the end with both in the expression, where you suppose $k$ to be constant. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The original question used $i$ instead of $k$, and used $k$ instead of $K$.  That is why it is confusing:  the $k$ in the original question is not the same as the $k$ in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Oh, I see now, in $k=i-1$ and $K=n-k$, it's not the same $k$, as you are renaming everything! Thanks for clarifying :)